# How does one convert a time zone name to zone code in java?

Tags: java, timezone

Having a program input as time zone name, as in 'Asia/Singapore'. It is required to convert it to the corresponding zone code, as 'SGT'.However, [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) class doesn't seem to have any method for it. What is the most convenient way of doing it?

PS: This works

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore");
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT));
```

Comment: It seems like you have found the correct, convenient way of doing it with a method.

Comment: I was suppose to answer that then I saw you edited post :

Comment: I recommend that you use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) and its `ZoneId` for your date, time and time zone work. The `TimeZone` class that you use had design issues and has been outdated for 10 years. Don’t use it.

Comment: Indeed `ZoneId` has a method specifically for this. Use `ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore").getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)`. It gives `SGT` as you requested.